# MySQL MATCH AGAINST using wildcards returns unexpected results with apostraphe

Tags: mysql, regex

I am doing a full text search as a user types and have come across an instance that does not behave as I expected.

I have the following pieces of data in a single column with a full text index:

1. Adrienna O'ROURKE   O'ROURKE Adrienna   F 1949-04-09 Miss  Single     6908
2. Olivia O'Toole   O'Toole Olivia   F 1989-06-30 Miss  Single  4362
3. Owen O'Leary   O'Leary Owen   M 1979-01-12 Mr.  Single  4533

The query below fails to match  "O'Rourke", but matches rows with "O'Toole" and "O'Leary":

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM pcObjects o  
WHERE  MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('*O\'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('*O\'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

This query matches the entry with "O'Rourke":

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM pcObjects o  
WHERE  MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('*O\'Rou*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('*O\'Rou*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

Can anyone explain why "O'Rourke" isn't being found in the first instance, but "O'Toole" is?  Thanks.

Comment: probably relevance. a word which appears in 50%+ of the results gets counted as noise. `O'` appears in ALL of your rows, so it's treated as noise. `O'Rou` only appears in ONE row (33% of the rows), therefore it's not noise. if you try `*Miss*`, you'll probably get the same thing - no results, because it's in 66% of the rows.

Comment: are you sure that you have the same *apostrophe* character in all 3 records?

Comment: I am sure the apostrophes are the same and have double-checked.  Also, if the apostrophe was difference, why would it start matching on the extended expression?

Comment: I actually have several thousand rows of data (the vast majority without O'). I have only showed the 3 that I through relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I know `BOOLEAN` mode return 1 or 0 there is no float relevance values so you just need:

```
SELECT distinct o.*
FROM pcObjects o  
WHERE  MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('O\'' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this  line:

```
ORDER BY MATCH(ObjectSearchData) AGAINST('*O\'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
```

has no sense in `BOOLEAN` mode all rows has **MATCH = 1**

Comment: Okay.  I can see that and will take it out, but removing the ORDER BY does not fix the matching issue.

Comment: @MarkDeVries but did you remove asterisks as well?

Comment: Yes.  Removing the asterisks actually drops me to 0 results.